# How to download a pdf file and attach it with a custom field in WP All Import Plugin?

Tags: wordpress, pdf, woocommerce, wpallimport

I am importing woo-commerce (1000) products from csv file. There is an option to download images and attach an image with custom fields.

Can anyone help to import pdf files and attach pdf in custom filed?

Please find below a screenshot of the image import section. I also tried there with pdf files but it's not working.

[image: Images import WpAllImport]

Comment: Have you already checked the plugin documentation? https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/images/overview/. Import images from URLs: https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/import-images-from-urls/. Import images from your server: https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/from-server/. Import images from your computer: https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/local-computer/.

Comment: Yes, I already checked but there is no option to download and import PDF file.

Comment: To help clarify for anyone new to All Import, a PDF file is treated the same way as an image file. So you can follow the steps for importing an image, and they will work for PDFs too.

Answer (score 3):

Try this way it worked for me:

```
function pdf_file_upload($post_id, $att_id, $file)
{
    $attachment = get_attached_media('application/pdf', $post_id);
    foreach($attachment as $attch):
        $url = $attch->guid;
        update_post_meta($post_id, "__document_file", $url);
    endforeach;
}
add_action('pmxi_attachment_uploaded', 'pdf_file_upload', 10, 3);
```

And in Other Post options section your pdf file should upload in this
[Click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nDIn.png)

Comment: Hey @chann did you add this PHP to the wpallimport function section in admin?